# Is there a replacement for pamusb on Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, usb, pam

It would seem that pamusb hasn't been supported for over a year now so is there a good and supported replacement available for Ubuntu 19.10+?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the [PamUUID](https://github.com/LuisRusso/PamUUID) module that is similar to the pamusb module. Inserting the correct usb drive into the computer grants access to the user.

I tested the module on Debian and FreeBSD. I expect the installation on Ubuntu to be similar to Debian. It requires compiling the module.

It is mainly the pam_uuid.c file which can be configured by writing a corresponding pam_uuid.h, in a [suckless](https://suckless.org/) way. The pen is detected by searching for the device corresponding an UUID in the pen. In the config file you only have to list the UUID user associations.

Comment: Hi, many thanks for that. I might use that if I can't find anything more suitable, but my quest has now moved on a step and I'm looking to unlock Ubuntu using the proximity of my phone. There was a product called BlueProximity, but that has also become unsupported. Thanks again.